# JS WordPress API fetch no response headers

Tags: rest-api, api

I am using the `@wordpress/api-fetch` package to try and retrieve the information for a Custom Post Type like so:

```
const query = {
 page: currentPage,
 parse: false,
 per_page: 1,
 status: 'publish',
};

const response = await apiFetch({
  path: addQueryArgs('/wp/v2/posts', query),
});

console.log(response); // returns the object
console.log(response.headers); // undefined
console.log(response.headers.get('X-WP-TotalPages')); // doesn't return anything
```

When I view the XHR request in Chrome, I can see the `x-wp-totalpages` header but how is it that the headers are undefined?

Answer (score 3):

I've finally got it, the `parse` is not an argument of query but is actually the second argument of apiFetch so it should've been:

```
const response = await apiFetch({
  path: addQueryArgs('/wp/v2/posts', query),
  parse: false,
});
```